# Creating, saving and editing information in Objects for Expense class

Tags: java, object

I am working on an expenses class but I am confused as of what needs to be done with the object that I have made. I think I am making this more complicated than it's suppose to be.

> develop an expense class that is responsible for recording and updating a single item such as gas, books, food, etc. Data fields will include category, description, date, amount, etc. To test your class, you should write a simple driver (a Java class with a main method) that instantiates at least two expense objects, testing all of the class’s functionality (i.e., all of the available methods). You may use constants for the data rather than inputting from the keyboard or an external file. This should remain in your driver.

This is some of the UML - that I believe to be important for this question

```
Expense

- categories: String [0..5] (categories = {"Misc", "education", "food",...})

- catNum: int

+ Expense(catNum:int, desc: String, date: SimpleDateFormat, amt: double, repeat: boolean)

+ Expense(desc: String, date: SimpleDateFormat, amt: double, repeat: boolean)
```

The problem I am having is with this:

> "  catNum is the index of the expense category. For example, if an
>   expense is for education I
>
> might instantiate an object using the first overloaded constructor:
>
> Alternatively, I might instantiate an Expense object for the football
>   tickets I just purchased
>
> using the no-arg constructor
>
> book = new Expense(1, “textbook”, ...
>
> tickets = new Expense( );
>
> "

I created one object in the Main - Expenses UserExpen = new Expenses(); 
But I don't really know what to do with it in order to do the above task.

I have asked my professor what they meant by this and would not explain really.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to ask? How to put this into codes?

Comment: I guess...I really don't know how to use it for "book = new Expense(1, "book name"....)"

Comment: This question from you or from your school is really hard to read. So what is your school asking you to do? Do you have the complete question from your school? You should ask a specific question, and you get a specific answer in no time. But so far, I still don't know what exactly is your question.

Comment: `But I don't really know what to do with it in order to do the above task.` What to do what the object you created depends on the task given by your school. (which is obviously not shown here)

Comment: added code and added a summary of what is suppose to be done. sorry for the late reply!

Comment: I have wrote a solution below, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all clearly stated from your school's assignment.

**First**, you have to create the Expense class (with given data in the UML) and the necessary constructors & methods. (As I see, you already done it partially)

**Second**, you have to instantiate an object from Expense class

```
For e.g: Expense userExpenses = new Expense(); //Pass in the necessary arguments
```

**Last**, test your Expense object in the driver class (the class which holds your **main()** method). Test that it works by invoking **all** the methods you created in Expense class and ensure the actual results is similar to the expected results.

**Example**:

```
userExpenses.printExpenses();  
System.out.println(userExpenses.getDesc());
userExpenses.delete();
```

Comment: OH, yeah. I must have just really been over thinking it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh no, lol sorry. I was in class. Thank you so much for your help! I'm almost done with the project now. I'm still learning java and forget simple things...sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost - It sounds like this is a question for a programming or related class. Although we can certainly help and maybe point you in the correct direction, it is generally against the rules to simply give answers/solutions.

That being said, you will also likely require your professor to give you guidance in regards to specific questions you have for the assignment.

As far as what you are asking, it sounds like you have already created the second case (e.g. an expense with no information, using the generic constructor). Try playing around with it and creating a second expense similar to the example. To be honest I am not sure what you are asking and the question is very broad.

**Edit** - In response to your comment, here is a quick explanation of what is happening. You can likely google Java Constructors or Java Methods & Parameters and get a full explanation.

Basically the code you have, you are creating a variable (named tickets, or book, etc) and assigning it to a newly created object. Similar in format to the below.

```
Expense book = new Expense(...);
```

This will create a variable named "book", and give it the value of "Expense(...)" where "..." is the values you assign to it. In your specific example **"book = new Expense(1, "book name"....)"** you are creating a new Expense object and passing the parameters "1", "book name", etc.

**Updated with new information**

So what I am seeing from your recent edits you need to create two things - an expense class and a driver class. As I don't feel the driver program is really the point of the assignment, I want to clear up your confusion on that first. Driver classes are usually separate from the actual classes (in your code, you have a main method inside of the expense class). This is not generally supposed to be the case. Please see the code below for an example.

```
public class ExpenseDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your test code here
        Expenses book = new Expenses(...);
    }
}
```

Now your question already indicated what you want to test, so I have included the example from above into the code. Please be aware the "..." is going to be your example hard-coded values for the expense. From here you will have to modify only the Expense class in order to get it working correctly.

I do have one question though - the question indicates you do not need to read input from the console, so why are you? The question is a lot simpler then you are making it.

Comment: added code and added a summary of what is suppose to be done. sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Did you write that code, or was it provided by the assignment?

Comment: I wrote all of it myself.